# Does the Fokker 70/100 Flight Management Computer really contain the ability to play Pong?

Tags: fms, fokker-100

This [clip](https://www.facebook.com/OfficialPilotsLounge/videos/764127507046469/) now circulating on Facebook ([YouTube link](https://youtu.be/BjFkIgusOnY?t=3s)) shows two pilots playing a game of Pong on the Fokker 70/100 Flight Management System (FMS). The manufacturer is presumably Honeywell.

Does this feature really exist?

Thoughts:

- I would have hoped they had better code review to catch this, but then again I'm not sure how these work. A few veteran old employees who know ADA or whatever sitting in a dark room down the corridor when the new intern shows up?
- The hardware is fairly old with corresponding limitations. As much as the flight displays (EICAS) can do decent graphics, the FMC seems pretty 'paginated' and slow to react to button presses.

---

Update: Thanks for the input. I was fairly certain it was fake but couldn't find the error. It also provoked some interesting software debate :)

Comment: Re: the hardware limitations, games like Pong are pretty simple: You could, at least in theory, play it on the Apollo AGS (I mean the display would be all wrong for it but you *could* certainly run the code. You could program and play play 5-card stud poker on it with the stock display unit if someone wanted to write the software). A quasi-modern FMC certainly has the *ability* to play pong from a compute-power standpoint, so it's really a question of "Did anyone really write and include that software?"

Comment: I strongly doubt it could happen, and would be interested in the answer. For 2 reasons. Adding useless code is adding possibility of bugs, this is irresponsible when lives are at stake. Giving crews some distraction when flying the aircraft falls in the same stupid category.

Comment: I have no knowledge of the FMS, but the clip is obviously a fabrication.  At 0:47 there is frame where the players finger is obscured by the "screen" that is hiding the actual display.

Comment: All avionics code is provided by 3 separate groups, independently reviewed by at least one other group, and tested according to the specification by yet another group(s).  It is also subject to regulatory oversight.  No way this is real.  There are no "easter eggs" in safety critical software.  It could only get through that stack by being very well hidden and the risk of side effects is just too great.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Good eye there, it is indeed.

Comment: Old hardware? Playing Pong? You realize [PONG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pong) came to the arcades in 1972 and was released as a home game in 1975? Just how old you think that Fokker is?

Comment: @Simon You'd be surprised by what makes it through the regulatory and QA process - I know of quite a few regulated medical devices that play a mean game of chess! A full source code audit is the only way to discover something like this, and even in aviation thats not general practice (DO-178B focuses on making sure requirements are met & no faults are introduced, but not on rooting out "extra stuff" not on the requirements list.)

Comment: @voretaq7 Full source code audits are carrried out by an independent group for all flight critical systems.

Comment: @Simon Full code audits are requried for *flight-critical* systems (of the "If this fails the aircraft falls out of the sky" variety, like say the FADEC controllers for the engines), but not *every* system on an aircraft. [The requirements AJRP described for the FMS](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/21034/64) are nearly identical to the requirements I work with every day, I know a few medical systems with easter eggs in them that have passed extremely thorough testing - one is actually *part of the self-test code* for its device.

Comment: @voretaq7 I think we're saying the same thing (I've also worked on such systems).  I did say flight critical.  I find it hard to believe that any development team would be stupid enough to put code like that in and any review team so negligent as to miss it.

Comment: @voretaq7 and even if a source code check is performed, with modular enough software it's quite possible to hook in other modules for which the source code was not provided to the auditors. Hardest part is setting up the scripts that create the package to be sent to the auditors to filter out your 'illegal' code in such a way that the scripts themselves seem innocent of such practices to the auditor (assuming those scripts are part of the audit).

Answer (score 12):

The 'clip' is obviously a fake. Standards for avionics software development and testing are rigorous, with development of flight critical software being done by separate (independent) groups and legally required to be reviewed by another (independent) group.

After that testing is done by another group/person who's certified by the regulatory authority. It is very very difficult and downright dangerous to have this kind of codes in flight critical system software.

Also, as BowlOfRed says, there is a point in the video where the finger (of copilot?) goes behind the screen.

[image: Screenshot]

Also, from the clip, it appears that the two 'players' predict each other's moves pretty accurately. I'm not very sure if that's the way it is played, but I doubt it.

Of course, to *prove* that something is impossible is not possible, but I'm quite certain that the clip is a fake.

Comment: While this particular clip may be fake, I've personally played Doom on telemetry equipment (doom source code was released and I was curious how much processing power our telemetry system had). Though in such cases the equipment wouldn't actually be installed on a plane. It would be a test unit on a rack in the lab.

Comment: @slebetman It is not a question of *can* it been done, rather one of *has* it been done. Porting games to the unlikeliness of instruments seems to be a hobby for coders (hell, someone played doom in a calculator). I'm pretty sure that ping pong can be played in most, if not all flight instruments with screen. If someone had shown this on the ground (lab), we'd probably had said 'wow, good job' and gone on our way. That it was shown in an aircraft is what intrigues everyone.

Answer (score 6):

It's probably fake but there's no reason why it couldn't be in and why it couldn't be approved like that.

An (The!) acceptable means of compliance to FAR/CS 23/25.1309 is DO-178. Airborne software is developed to meet a Design Assurance Level (DAL) which is derived from the aircraft level Functional Hazard Analysis and Preliminary System Safety Assessment (see SAE ARP 4761).

Every FMC/FMS I've every worked on has been DAL C which means that the failure is 'Major' defined as the "failure is significant, but has a lesser impact than a Hazardous failure (for example, leads to passenger discomfort rather than injuries) or significantly increases crew workload (safety related)".

For DAL C development, independence is only required for meeting the Software QA aspect. The software verification activity does not have to independent of the developer. However, for DAL C code, there is a requirement to complete full statement structural coverage, i.e. structure has to be tested at least once during the formal verification testing (i.e a decision has to be tested true OR false, not true AND false).

Therefore the Software Verification Cases and Procedures (SVCP) would have to have had a test for the pong game in or else structural coverage would have shown the code to be 'Dead Code' and it would have to be removed.

The certification authority (FAA, EASA or otherwise) would not typically review the SVCP or the results (SVR).

The unit will also, most likely, have a Technical Standard Order (TSO) approval but as long as the performance requirements are met for the applicable TSO (e.g. TSO-C115c) the approval will be granted.

Comment: Reposting my comments. *Structure has to be tested at least once during the formal verification testing (i.e a decision has to be tested true OR false, not true AND false)*: I assume you mean both TRUE and FALSE branches have to be tested, else the test coverage would not be complete

Comment: I think I understand your point: All statements vs all decisions. However I don't see the point to checking a [SWITCH-CASE](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson5.html) with 100 CASE blocks of instructions by looking only one CASE block (e.g. if an infinite loop exists in the second CASE block). Using an analogy with an electrical rotary switch with 100 positions, there is little use to check the first position doesn't create a problem, and ignoring the 99 others.

Comment: All the cases would generally be covered by the requirements based testing. Also, for reasons of reducing software complexity and  improving testability of the software (cyclomatic complexity / McCabe complexity), the number of cases in a switch case should be limited (some compilers struggle with more than 32 anyway). Also, nesting switch cases or nesting conditional statements within the switch should be avoided. The overiding testing is always the requirements based testing. Testing just to meet coverage requirements alone is meaningless.

Comment: The premise of all testing for all DO-178 compliant airborne software, regardless of DAL , is requirements based testing. This is done for both for the normal range and robustness (invalid conditions, invalid inputs, out-of-range, over-framing, invalid state transitions etc.)

For DAL D (Software that can cause or contribute to a Minor failure condition ), this is all that is required and only for the high level requirements. For DAL C (Major), DAL B (Hazardous/Severe-Major) or DAL A (Catastrophic) requirements based testing on low-level requirements also has to be completed.

Comment: Additionally for DAL C 100% structural STATEMENT coverage has to be demonstrated (i.e. - yes OR no)

Additionally for DAL B 100% structural DECISION coverage has to be demonstrated (i.e. - yes AND no)

Additionally for DAL A 100% structural Modified Condition/Decision coverage (MC/DC) has to be demonstrated. Put simply, this tests every path through the software between an entry and an exit point.

Comment: As we test for requirements, you will often find that even for level D and especially level C software, a high %age of Decision coverage is demonstrated anyway. Unit tests are only used to provide coverage on areas of code that may not normally be executed i.e. error detection and exception handling.

Comment: As my own answer has been flagged for removal, this one should be flagged probably as well. It also only speculates that could possibly be.